# Trying to export activities using AXIOS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I've been trying to build a website using React and it has been going relatively good until now. I'm following a tutorial and doing everything "by the book" but I still end up getting an error when I try to send data from my API to the frontend.

This is the part that gets the data.

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { IActivity } from '../models/activity';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost5000';

const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data;

const requests = {
    get: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(responseBody),
    post: (url: string, body: {}) => axios.post(url, body).then(responseBody),
    put: (url: string, body: {}) => axios.put(url, body).then(responseBody),
    del: (url: string) => axios.delete(url).then(responseBody)
}

const Activities = {
    list: (): Promise<IActivity[]> => requests.get('/activities'),
    details: (id: string) => requests.get(`/activities/${id}`),
    create: (activity: IActivity) => requests.post('/activities', activity),
    update: (activity: IActivity) => requests.put(`/activities/${activity.id}`, activity),
    delete: (id: string) => requests.del(`/activities/${id}`)
};

export default {
    Activities
}
```

And this is on my App.tsx

```
useEffect(() => {
   agent.Activities.list()
      .then((response) => {
        let activities: IActivity[] = [];
        response.forEach(activity =>{
          activity.date = activity.date.split('.')[0]
          activities.push(activity);
        })
        setActivities(activities);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: `'http://localhost5000'` your url is malformed `http://localhost:5000` to reach localhost on port 5000

Answer (score 1):

Your url is malformed

Change `http://localhost5000` to `http://localhost:5000` to reach localhost on port 5000

Comment: Bro I could kiss u rn. Thank you so much